# Does java 8 support local lambda variables?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Consider a code (non compilable):

```
 List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
 list.stream().map(s ->
         String variable = method(s)
         variable + "debug"
 );

 private String method(String s) {
         return s;
 }
```

Line `String variable = method(s)` is not compiled.

Can I define a local variable *inside* lambda expression or it is forbidden by design?

Comment: judging by the `debug`, don't you want to `peek()`?

Comment: Have a look at [JLS section 15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2) defining lambda bodies.

Comment: What error do you get? What makes you think you can't have local variables?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes however multi-statement lambdas need to wrap the code block in braces.  You also need to correctly use semicolons at the ends of the statements.  Also you need to use the `return` keyword.

```
list.stream().map(s ->{
            String variable = method(s);
            return variable + "debug";
        }
    );
```

Single statement lambdas have an implied `return` to save you from typing and makes the lambda more readable.